# Update and save model data from a view function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am looking to create an automation strategy for data validation via the Django Admin. My Idea is to save transaction data in my Admin panel then later query the database for validation. I am still on my training wheels with Django, and any help will be much appreciated.

the initial event will be triggered through to this JS function

```
function save_this_data_to_models(event) {
  user_name = "user name";
  data =
    "I need this data auto saved to my models in admin via this called view fucntion";

  window.fetch(`/save_this_data_to_models?data=${data}&name=${user_name}`);

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

the JS function calls and passes user data to this Python View function

```
def save_this_data_to_models(request):

    # the data i need saved to my models
    data = request.GET.get('data', 'default')
    user_name = request.GET.get('name', 'default')
    print('')
    print('==========')
    print(user_name)
    print('==========')
    print('')
    print('=================================================================================')
    print(data)
    print('=================================================================================')
    print('')

    return HttpResponse(request)
```

the prints are for my sanity.
this is my modles.py file where i want to save this data automatically in my Admin site

```
from django.db import models


class Name(models.Model):
    # defining the fields i want to be saved to the database
    User_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.User_name


class Data(models.Model):
    # defining the fields i want to be saved to the database
    Data = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Data
```

There is a question that's some what near to my solution but I could not make it work for me, this is what i tried but i probably wasn't using the information right.

Name_object = Name.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
Name_object.some_field = summary_data[0]
... here the rest of values

Name_object.save()

I have a feeling that this is what i need to do but i do not know how to implement it. I need clarity from the imports to the 'save()' function because I'm surely missing something here.

Comment: Django has class-based views which make it easier to handle requests. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/